# How we can create multiple spinners with MySQL database value in Android?

Tags: android, mysql

I am working with a project with multiple spinners in a single app, which fetches data from a MySQL database and shown in spinners. In this code, only one spinner is used, it collect data from MySQL database, how we can use more than one spinner in this.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<>();
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
Spinner sp,sp1;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_layout,R.id.txt,listItems);
    sp.setAdapter(adapter);
     }
 public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    BackTask bt=new BackTask();
    bt.execute();
}
  private class BackTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    ArrayList<String> list;
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        list=new ArrayList<>();
    }
    protected Void doInBackground(Void...params){
        InputStream is=null;
        String result="";
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost= new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.2/agriculture.php");
            HttpResponse response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            // Get our response as a String.
            is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //convert response to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result+=line;
            }
            is.close();
            //result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{

            JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jArray = jsono.getJSONArray("actors");
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject=jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                list.add(jsonObject.getString("name"));

            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        listItems.addAll(list);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: post your code which you try for this

Comment: @ZakiPathan, I  posted my code.. please check

Comment: I think your listItems is blank? where you add something in listItems arraylist? @Jincy

Comment: check my answer below @Jincy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<>();
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
Spinner sp,sp1;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

     }
 public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    BackTask bt=new BackTask();
    bt.execute();
}
  private class BackTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    ArrayList<String> list;
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        list=new ArrayList<>();
    }
    protected Void doInBackground(Void...params){
        InputStream is=null;
        String result="";
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost= new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.2/agriculture.php");
            HttpResponse response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            // Get our response as a String.
            is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //convert response to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result+=line;
            }
            is.close();
            //result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{

            JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jArray = jsono.getJSONArray("actors");
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject=jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                list.add(jsonObject.getString("name"));

            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        listItems.addAll(list);
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_layout,R.id.txt,listItems);
    sp.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

try this. set adapter after your listitem is filled. If this doesn't work feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Spinners are quite easy to implement - 
1) Fetch your data in an ArrayList from SQLite DB.
2) Create a spinner - Spinner abcd;
3) Create an ArrayAdapter with the ArrayList that you defined.
4) Make adapter a drop down - myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
5) Set the adapter of the spinner to the ArrayAdapter- abcd.setAdapter(myAdapter).